# Pandas - Creating new dataframe with date as one df and staff details in another df

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a Dataframe with list of all dates in a calander month.

I have another Dataframe that has attendance of staff by day. I am trying to build a new Dataframe that would merge both these Dataframe.

Given below is how df1 looks:

```
date
10/1/2018
10/2/2018
10/3/2018
```

df2 looks as below:

```
date,emp_id
10/1/2018,staff_1
10/1/2018,staff_2
10/1/2018,staff_3
10/2/2018,staff_1
10/2/2018,staff_2
10/3/2018,staff_3
```

I am trying to merge the above two data frames such that the output is as below:

```
,10/1/2018,10/2/2018,10/3/2018
staff_1,1,1,1
staff_2,1,1,0
staff_3,1,0,1
```

Could anyone advice how could I create this final Dataframe given the data at hand, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with default inner join and then [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) if need count values:

```
df = df1.merge(df2)
print (df)
        date   emp_id
0  10/1/2018  staff_1
1  10/1/2018  staff_2
2  10/1/2018  staff_3
3  10/2/2018  staff_1
4  10/2/2018  staff_2
5  10/3/2018  staff_3
6  10/2/2018  staff_2
7  10/3/2018  staff_3

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df1 = pd.crosstab(df['emp_id'], df['date'])
print (df1)
date     2018-10-01  2018-10-02  2018-10-03
emp_id                                     
staff_1           1           1           0
staff_2           1           2           0
staff_3           1           0           2
```

Or [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) with `max` for indicator columns:

```
df2 = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('emp_id')['date']).max(level=0)
print (df2)
         2018-10-01  2018-10-02  2018-10-03
emp_id                                     
staff_1           1           1           0
staff_2           1           1           0
staff_3           1           0           1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pd.pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
In [2209]: df = df1.merge(df2)

In [2205]: pd.pivot_table(df, index='emp_id', columns='date', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
Out[2205]: 
date     10/1/2018  10/2/2018  10/3/2018
emp_id                                  
staff_1          1          1          0
staff_2          1          1          0
staff_3          1          0          1
```